# Android Studio has extra unkown device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am trying to do some remote debugging in Android Studio.

Recently I've had an issue where an extra device will pop-up named `Unknown Device` so when i run `adb tcpip 5555` I get the error message: `error: more than one device/emulator`

So I need to get rid of this `Unknown Device`

So far here is what I've tried:

- `adb kill-server`
- Invalidate Android Studio Cache and restart
- Restart my computer
- Looked for anything in `~/.android/avd/` which may cause it (There was nothing)
- Ran Android Studios troubleshooter which restarted adb

None of the above worked, does anyone have any idea what this `Unknown Device` may be, and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: Did you try theses commands in Android studio terminal?

Comment: @majuran yes, and a regular terminal as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I did a check for updates in android studio, and there was a minor update available. After installing the minor update, the problem went away - It must've been some bug in whatever Android Studio version I had.